# Change Button text in excel using xlwings/pywin32

Tags: excel, pywin32, xlwings

I create a FormControl button using `shape=ws.shapes.api.AddFormControl(0,1,1,1,1)`.

The button name can be changed `shape.Name='new_name'`.

How to change the text on the button? I have tried the following, none of them works.

`shape.Caption = new_text'`

`shape.Text='new_text'`

`shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text='new_text'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the first 0 is 'xlButtonControl'
You can set the set the text on the button like so

```
shape = ws.shapes.api.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, 50, 50, 200, 30)
shape.OLEFormat.Object.Text = "Text on Button"
```